# Finding values based on specific categories

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I was wondering how would find estimated values based on several different categories. Two of the columns are categorical, one of the other columns contains two strings of interest and the last contain numeric values
I have a csv file called sports.csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#loading the data into data frame
df = pd.read_csv('sports.csv')
```

I'm trying to find a suggested `price` for a `Gym` that have both baseball and basketball as well as `enrollment` from 240 to 260 given they are from `region` 4 and of `type` 1

```
Region  Type    enroll  estimates   price   Gym
2   1   377 0.43    40  Football|Baseball|Hockey|Running|Basketball|Swimming|Cycling|Volleyball|Tennis|Ballet
4   2   100 0.26    37  Baseball|Tennis
4   1   347 0.65    61  Basketball|Baseball|Ballet
4   1   264 0.17    12  Swimming|Ballet|Cycling|Basketball|Volleyball|Hockey|Running|Tennis|Baseball|Football
1   1   286 0.74    78  Swimming|Basketball
0   1   210 0.13    29  Baseball|Tennis|Ballet|Cycling|Basketball|Football|Volleyball|Swimming
0   1   263 0.91    31  Tennis
2   2   271 0.39    54  Tennis|Football|Ballet|Cycling|Running|Swimming|Baseball|Basketball|Volleyball
3   3   247 0.51    33  Baseball|Hockey|Swimming|Cycling
0   1   109 0.12    17  Football|Hockey|Volleyball
```

I don't know how to piece everything together. I apologize if the syntax is incorrect I'm just beginning Python. So far I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#loading the data into data frame
df = pd.read_csv('sports.csv')

#group 4th region and type 1 together where enrollment is in between 240 and 260
group = df[df['Region'] == 4] df[df['Type'] == 1] df[240>=df['Enrollment'] <=260 ]
#split by pipe chars to find gyms that contain both Baseball and Basketball
df['Gym'] = df['Gym'].str.split('|')
df['Gym'] = df['Gym'].str.contains('Baseball'& 'Basketball')

price = df.loc[df['Gym'], 'Price']
```

Should I do a groupby instead? If so, how would I include the columns `Type`==1  `Region` ==4 and enrollment from 240 to 260 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas: filter rows of DataFrame with operator chaining](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869910/pandas-filter-rows-of-dataframe-with-operator-chaining)

Comment: You asked the same question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38677504/finding-specific-strings-within-a-column-and-finding-the-max-corresponding-to-th My answer to that question could be used to answer this one., also.. READ ALL THE ANSWERS.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `mask` with all your conditions specified and then use the mask for subsetting:

```
mask = (df['Region'] == 4) & (df['Type'] == 1) & \
       (df['enroll'] <= 260) & (df['enroll'] >= 240) & \
        df['Gym'].str.contains('Baseball') & df['Gym'].str.contains('Basketball')

df['price'][mask]
# Series([], name: price, dtype: int64)
```

which returns empty, since there is no record satisfying all conditions as above.

Comment: Thank you for your response, sorry if this is a dumb question, but how do I print it's output? When I run print df['Price'][mask] it just gives me Series([], Name: Price, dtype: int64)

Comment: That's because there is nothing in your data frame satisfy all the conditions, and you get empty results. If you have a larger data frame or you modify your conditions so that there are some records satisfying the conditions, you should be able to get the results printed.

Comment: I tried adding more values to make it true but it still gave me Series([], Name: Price, dtype: int64)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an instance that would actually meet your criteria, or else you will get an empty result. You want to use `df.loc` with conditions as follows:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd, numpy as np, io
In [2]: in_string = io.StringIO("""Region  Type    enroll  estimates   price   Gym
    ...: 2   1   377 0.43    40  Football|Baseball|Hockey|Running|Basketball|Swimming|Cycling|Volleyball|Tennis|Ballet
    ...: 4   2   100 0.26    37  Baseball|Tennis
    ...: 4   1   247 0.65    61  Basketball|Baseball|Ballet
    ...: 4   1   264 0.17    12  Swimming|Ballet|Cycling|Basketball|Volleyball|Hockey|Running|Tennis|Baseball|Football
    ...: 1   1   286 0.74    78  Swimming|Basketball
    ...: 0   1   210 0.13    29  Baseball|Tennis|Ballet|Cycling|Basketball|Football|Volleyball|Swimming
    ...: 0   1   263 0.91    31  Tennis
    ...: 2   2   271 0.39    54  Tennis|Football|Ballet|Cycling|Running|Swimming|Baseball|Basketball|Volleyball
    ...: 3   3   247 0.51    33  Baseball|Hockey|Swimming|Cycling
    ...: 0   1   109 0.12    17  Football|Hockey|Volleyball""")

In [3]: df = pd.read_csv(in_string,delimiter=r"\s+")

In [4]: df.loc[df.Gym.str.contains(r"(?=.*Baseball)(?=.*Basketball)") 
    ...:        & (df.enroll <= 260) & (df.enroll >= 240) 
    ...:        & (df.Region == 4) & (df.Type == 1), 'price']
Out[4]: 
2    61
Name: price, dtype: int64
```

Note I used a regex pattern for contains that essentially acts as an AND operator for regex. You could simply have done another conjunction of `.contains` conditions for Basketball and Baseball.